# Can't get firefox to render the right size in a headless xvfb instance

Tags: firefox, headless, xvfb

I can start the xvfb instance just fine

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x24
```

I can then launch firefox and have it load correctly but the window is always smaller than the resolution I set during the xvfb command.

```
firefox http://www.ebay.com --display=:1
```

[image]

You can see the black bar, that's the full resolution. It appears it's sizing to what the page wants but it will never fill it out completely.

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: I want to get an accurate screenshot at different resolutions. Since this is not the exact resolution it messes up my tests.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution, not pretty but works. Uses `xdotool` to set size after `Firefox` is running.

First:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible firefox
```

This will display a single window ID, `windowid`. Then:

```
xdotool windowmove windowid 0 0
xdotool windowsize windowid 1280 720
```

You must first do the `windowmove` and follow it by the `windowsize`.

In some cases once I did this, the size and position were correct forever more, in other cases had to run again each time I ran `Firefox`.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the border is there and compensate accordingly in your capture.  If you need 1024x768, then set the screen size to 1034x778 and capture 1024x768

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1034x778x24 > /dev/null &
ffmpeg -t 1 -s 1024x768 -f x11grab -i :1.0+10,10 -f mjpeg screenshot.png
```